# Why is CakePHP hashing my password twice?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, hash

I'm Using CakePHPs standard Auth mechanism, but I have some problems with that.
Everytime a user logs in the password got hashed twice.

I have the Auth Component in the `var $componets Array` in the `app_controller.php` 
and one in the `var $components` Array from my `users_controller` where the login action is
defined. I have defined a `beforeFilter` in my `users_controller` like this

```
  function beforeFilter(){
 parent::beforeFilter();      
  $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
```

Now when I print out my $this->data in cakephps hashPassword funktion in the Auth component file (auth.php line 854) like this

```
 function hashPasswords($data) {
```

pr($data);

I can see that `pr(...)` gets called twice.

Can anybody tell me why this is, or can help me to find a solution, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only include the Auth component in your app_controller.php, since your UsersController extends AppController, the Auth component will be loaded inside your UsersController automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if it's loaded in the app_controller, there's no need to load it again anywhere else.
[troubleshooting auth problems](http://book.cakephp.org/view/565/Troubleshooting-Auth-Problems)

Try to disable the default hashing functions, with your own, so you may debug it more easily
[change hash function](http://book.cakephp.org/view/566/Change-Hash-Function)